# Why does my Login component flash whenever i reload my dashbord component in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

The problem i'm having is that my login component flashes for a split second whenever I reload my dashboard

> **I'm using postgres database. This is my app.js component it verify whether the header has received a token and then set isAuthenticated to true**

```
const App = () => {

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
 
  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean)
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   
    // check if the person is still Authenticated
    const isAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/auth/verify', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { token: localStorage.token},
        })
        const data = await res.json()
       // if authenticated, then
       if(data === true) {
        await setIsAuthenticated(true)
       } else {
        await setIsAuthenticated(false)
        setLoading(false)
       }

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
      }
    }
    isAuth()
  })
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <div className='container'>
            <Switch>
  
              <Route exact path='/login' render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Login {...props} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> } />
  
              <Route exact path='/register' render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Register {...props} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />} />
              
              <Route exact path='/dashboard' render={props => isAuthenticated  ? <Dashboard {...props} loading={loading} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/login' /> } />
  
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
```

> **This is my Login component**

```
const Login = () => {
 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            // Get the body data
            const body = { email, password }
            const res = await fetch('/auth/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            })
            const data = await res.json()
            if(data.token) {
                 // save token to local storage
                localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
                setAuth(true)
                toast.success('Login Successful')
            } else {
                setAuth(false)
                toast.error(data)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        }
        
    }
}
```

> **And this is my dashboard component that just displays only the name of the logged-in user**

```
const Dashboard = ({ setAuth, loading }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const getName = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('/dashboard', {
                    method: 'GET', 
                    // Get the token in localStorage into the header
                    headers: { token: localStorage.token }
                })
                const data = await res.json()

                setName(data.user_name)

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err.message)
            }
        }
        getName()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    // Log out 
    const logOut = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.removeItem("token")
        setAuth(false)
        window.location.reload()
        toast.success('Logged Out')
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className='mt-5'>Dashboard</h1>
            <p>Hello, {name}</p>
            <button className='btn btn-primary my-3' onClick={e => logOut(e)}>Log Out</button>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Below is a giphy image of what happens when I reload my dashboard

[image]

Comment: please record a video of your flash, so we can look it and give you the appropriate solution

Comment: i have added it in my edit. you can see it now